# Need Desire output using shell

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to get desired output using a shell script.

Input:

```
aaabbcaaabbcc
```

Desired Output:

```
a3b2ca3b2c2
```

Command should print number of occurrence of each alphabet only when it's greater than 1, i.e `aaab` should come as `a3b`.

I tried with below commands and they didn't work for me, as I have to pass characters manually to my command.

```
echo "aaabbcaaabbcc" | grep -o a  
echo "aaabbcaaabbcc" | uniq -c  
echo "aaabbcaaabbcc" | grep -o a | uniq -c
```

I am unable to find how I can split it character-wise and then check number of occurrences.

Comment: 1) Where is the input coming from? Is it the contents of a text file? The output of a command or application? 2) What have you tried to do? If you just want to replace the string in the input with the string in the desired output then you don't need a shell script. Have a look at the `sed` command.

Comment: You seem to want to implement some form run-length encoding. What issues are you having with doing this?

Comment: There are far too many possible answers with this incomplete and underspecified question, starting with `echo a3b2ca3b2c2`.

Comment: Related: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: @Kusalananda, Is this some famous problem which i asked here ? u have this solved in all possible languages i can imagine of. Hats off!!! I tired understanding the awk version of solution but its too hard for me . Can u plz help to make me understand this .

Comment: @Machine [Run-length encoding (RLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) is a well known and simple way of compressing highly redundant data. If you have a _particular_ issue with the `awk` variant on the Rosetta page that I linked to, then you may want to ask another question about it.  Pure programming questions relating to the implementation of specific algorithms would arguably be more suitable on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) though.

Comment: Try this, `echo "aaabbcaaabbcc" | grep -o . | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" }; {print $2$1}'`

Comment: @msp9011, Good if we dont know about**fold** , but i just modified ur script further to get exact answer as its even throwing count for char which are just 1 in number----------------------------- echo "aaabbcaaabbcc" | grep -o . | uniq -c | \
> while read count char
> do
> if [[ $count -gt 1 ]]
> then
> echo -n $char$count
> else
> echo -n $char
> fi
> done

Answer (score 2):

```
str="aaabbcaaabbcc"

echo $str | fold -w1 | uniq -c | \
while read count char; do
  if [ $count -gt 1 ]; then
    printf "$char$count"
  else
    printf "$char"
  fi
done
```

> a3b2ca3b2c2

Comment: This would unfortunately fail if the string contained backslashes or percentage signs, or filename globbing patterns, or started with a dash, or if `IFS` was set to a set of digits or letters.

Comment: @ Fedor Dikarev , I never knew about **fold** which can split a word vertically in char form. Thanks for this